# demostration of interger part integration.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help for solving this demostration, I  appreciate your suggestions very much.

$$\begin{array}{rclr}
\int ^{n}_{0}[x] dx= \frac{n(n-1)}{2} 
\end{array}$$

Pd. If you have any suggestion of a book that deepens on the subject please communicate it.

Comment: @KennyLog_ins I don't agree with your edit.  Perhaps surprisingly, [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) means something completely different. The meaning of the original phrase "interger part integration" in the title referred to integrating the [integer part function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html), which is what this question is about; the new title is misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice, let $n$ be an integer then using property of definite integral, we have $$\int_{0}^{n}[x]dx=\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx+\int_{1}^{2}[x]dx+\int_{2}^{3}[x]dx+\ldots+\int_{n-1}^{n}[x]dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}(0)dx+\int_{1}^{2}1dx+\int_{2}^{3}2dx+\ldots+\int_{n-1}^{n}(n-1)dx$$  $$=0+1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)$$ $$\implies \int_{0}^{n}[x]dx=1+2+3+\ldots +(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: $\lfloor x \rfloor = k$ for $x \in [k,k+1)$ for $k = 0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$. Hence
$$\int_0^n \lfloor x \rfloor \; dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \lfloor x \rfloor \; dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} k \; dx,$$
where the integrand is a constant with respect to $x$.

Answer (score -1):

For any positive integer n,  $[x]=n$ for $n\le x< n+1$
$$\int_0^n[x]dx=0+1+2+3+4+\ldots +(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$